# Extract lines from text file

Tags: regex, macos, terminal

I have a text file in which I would like to extract certain rows. For example keep row 1:3 delete row 4:7 and keep row 8:10. Ideally, the new text file would be a new one with *_appended* in its name.

I suspect you would use regex in the terminal, but I have about one hours worth of knowledge in regex.

Operating systems: I am on OS X, by partner is on windows 10 and we have an old slow computer with latest Ubuntu and Linux Mint on it.

## Go from this file

```
*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : eGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(0,0,0)
Distribution    : norm 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
mu     -0.000035    0.000278  -0.12558 0.900064
omega  -0.131803    0.012416 -10.61557 0.000000
alpha1 -0.104974    0.015901  -6.60185 0.000000
beta1   0.984519    0.001600 615.23328 0.000000
gamma1  0.106778    0.022386   4.76980 0.000002

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
mu     -0.000035    0.000716  -0.048756 0.961114
omega  -0.131803    0.038617  -3.413124 0.000642
alpha1 -0.104974    0.050081  -2.096092 0.036074
beta1   0.984519    0.005043 195.217257 0.000000
gamma1  0.106778    0.071636   1.490573 0.136074

LogLikelihood : 10033 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------

Akaike       -5.7897
Bayes        -5.7808
Shibata      -5.7897
Hannan-Quinn -5.7865

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                      1.368 0.24209
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][2]     3.404 0.10913
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]     5.817 0.09929
d.o.f=0
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                      4.649 0.03108
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]     6.972 0.05267
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][9]     9.014 0.08075
d.o.f=2

Weighted ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
            Statistic Shape Scale P-Value
ARCH Lag[3]    0.8635 0.500 2.000  0.3528
ARCH Lag[5]    2.1150 1.440 1.667  0.4464
ARCH Lag[7]    3.7967 2.315 1.543  0.3768

Nyblom stability test
------------------------------------
Joint Statistic:  0.7384
Individual Statistics:              
mu     0.11217
omega  0.15329
alpha1 0.23532
beta1  0.14787
gamma1 0.06221

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Joint Statistic:         1.28 1.47 1.88
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------
                   t-value     prob sig
Sign Bias          0.82347 0.410299    
Negative Sign Bias 0.08741 0.930353    
Positive Sign Bias 2.58593 0.009752 ***
Joint Effect       7.08211 0.069326   *


Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     69.83    9.802e-08
2    30     90.41    3.146e-08
3    40    107.39    2.628e-08
4    50    134.93    5.809e-10


Elapsed time : 0.3566
```

## End up with that file

```
GARCH Model : eGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(0,0,0)
Distribution    : norm

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
mu     -0.000035    0.000716  -0.048756 0.961114
omega  -0.131803    0.038617  -3.413124 0.000642
alpha1 -0.104974    0.050081  -2.096092 0.036074
beta1   0.984519    0.005043 195.217257 0.000000
gamma1  0.106778    0.071636   1.490573 0.136074

LogLikelihood : 10033

Information Criteria
------------------------------------

Akaike       -5.7897
Bayes        -5.7808
Shibata      -5.7897
Hannan-Quinn -5.7865

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                      1.368 0.24209
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][2]     3.404 0.10913
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]     5.817 0.09929
d.o.f=0
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                      4.649 0.03108
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]     6.972 0.05267
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][9]     9.014 0.08075
d.o.f=2

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Joint Statistic:         1.28 1.47 1.88
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------
                   t-value     prob sig
Sign Bias          0.82347 0.410299
Negative Sign Bias 0.08741 0.930353
Positive Sign Bias 2.58593 0.009752 ***
Joint Effect       7.08211 0.069326   *
```

Comment: Is there any logic to what stays and what goes?

Comment: what information you want to get from that text file?

Comment: what would be the result?

Comment: Ideally, the result would be a new text file would be a new one with _appended in its name having content as the second block of code as seen in the question. A text based logical filtering would be. 
1. start on "Dynamics" stop on "Optimal"
2. start on "Robust" stop on "Weighted ARCH LM"
3. start on "Sign Bias Test" stop on the line before adjusted"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed '4,7d' your_file > your_file_appended
```

It will remove line 4-7 from file and write modified contents to new file named `your_file_appended`